# ImageResizer.Net - not resizing images

Tags: css, imageresizer

I have recently downloaded [Image Resizer .Net](http://imageresizing.net/download) due to being interested in to what it has to offer, you can see three libraries in the link I have supplied, I've gone ahead and downloaded all of them.

Rebuilt the project, then navigated to my view and specified a width,height and mode for an image that's getting displayed as shown here.

```
 <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dncu6pqpm/image/upload/q_80/@profilePic?w=50&h=50&mode=crop">
```

This URL is of a car its width is 402 and its height is 300, I want to resize is just to test the functionality, but it doesn't seem to change its size? could this be to do with the fact its referencing an external image?

Update.

This is the rendered HTML

```
<img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dncu6pqpm/image/upload/cunaulfla05xjzb5y2fe.jpg?w=50&h=50&mode=crop">
```

Answer (score 0):

I read your question again and notice the part that your trying to apply it to an external image. Image Resizer will not work with external images as the images is requested directly to the external repository. In order for the image to be able to be resized it has to be served by your hosting server's IIS, where your website (with Image Resizer) is installed.

Make a quick test with a local image and see if that works.